# How to embed sqlite file inside a custom IOS framework and what is the path of that

Tags: sqlite, frameworks, bundle

I am just creating one framework by following below post

[Jaymehthas blog that how to create a custom framework](http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-create-custom-ios-framework.html)

But I need to add sqlite database file inside a custom framework, How can i do that and how i can get the path of the file which is there inside a framework